# Angular JS: Add and remove terms from checkboxes in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a miller column constructed in Angular and Bootstrap.

http://codepen.io/smlombardi/pen/WGwGbY

In the second column, clicking the word (link) opens the third column, but I need to have the *checkbox* add that word to an array of search terms.

If the checkbox is UN-checked, I need to *remove* that word from the array of search terms. As you can see in the pen, I have the *adding* part working, but un-checking the box adds the word again.

I realize what I need to do is somehow check the state of the checkbox and if it's true add the word and if it's false check the array for the word (string) and pop it out of the array.

I can't figure out how to check only the checkbox that was clicked.

```
   <div class="col-xs-3 inner-column">
<div class="panel panel-default">

  <div class="list-group">
    <div class="list-group-item" ng-class="{active: $index === pmt.millercolumn.level1Selected }" ng-repeat="level1 in pmt.millercolumn.level1 track by $index">
     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="activeSearchTerm" ng-change="pmt.change($index)" id="ng-change-example1" />
      <a href="" ng-click="pmt.getSublevel2($index)" >
        {{level1.name}}
        <i class="pull-right fa fa-angle-right fa-lg"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the `ng-change` on the checkbox calls:

```
   _this.change = function (index) {
    var searchTerm = _this.millercolumn.level1[index].name;
    _this.searchTerms.push(searchTerm);
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in place of your _change function it works for sure

```
 _this.change = function (index) {
    console.log('Clicked on', _this.millercolumn.level1[index].name);
    var searchTerm = _this.millercolumn.level1[index].name;
    var searchIndex = _this.searchTerms.indexOf(searchTerm);
    if (searchIndex == -1) {   // If new push
       _this.searchTerms.push(searchTerm);
    }
    else {                    // Else remove item
      _this.searchTerms.splice(searchIndex, 1);
    }
    console.log(_this.searchTerms);
  };
```

Working codepen demo : http://codepen.io/krishcdbry/pen/EgKgBv

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're thinking in a jquery mindset where you need to handle events when something changes. An easier way would be to make each checkbox correspond to an item in the array, so the ng-model would be something like `level1.isSelected`. Then, to construct your search terms array, use scope.$watch and pass true as the 3rd argument to deep watch your array of items. When a checkbox is checked, your watch will be called and you can reconstruct the search terms array by plucking the terms of the list items that are selected.

Answer (score 0):

You're running the same code no matter if the checkbox is checked or not.  Try something like this:

```
_this.change = function (index, checked) {
  var searchTerm = _this.millercolumn.level1[index].name;
if(checked){


    _this.searchTerms.push(searchTerm);
}
if(!checked){
 _this.searchTerms.splice(searchTerm);
}
  };
```

Comment: Yes, I figured, but "checked" is what trips me up, how do I get that?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, this is what I did, which works:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="level1.isSelected" ng-change="pmt.change($index, level1)" id="mycb" />

  _this.change = function (index, item) {
    if (item.isSelected) {
      _this.searchTerms.push(item.name);
    } else {
      var termToRemove = item.name;
      for (var i = _this.searchTerms.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (_this.searchTerms[i] === termToRemove) {
          _this.searchTerms.splice(i, 1);
        }
      }
    }
  };
```